# getting error while run npm init command on windows 7 form cmd

Tags: node.js, npm

I' m following some tutorials for creating SPA with node.js. First i check the node is install or not on my system by this command :

**D:\zaeem\MEAN>node --version
v6.9.1**

I' m sure that npm is already installed on my system.Now I am running command "npm init" to create package.json file, at route directry of project.It gives me

> error:can't find module ./pem

[image: screen shot of error]

Please let me know .What I 'm doing wrong ?